# jquery ui binding to sortable recieve event when dealing with nested sortables

Tags: events, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a need to sort columns and separately I need to be able to sort fields accross columns and would like to hook into the col sort finished so that I can save the new column position and then also hook into the field sort finished event so that I can save the new field position

There is a jsFiddle showing an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/chrisp_68/pKVqU/10/) (doesn't seem to work in IE, but thats a different story!). What this shows is that when a column is dragged no alert is shown and when a field is dragged between columns the field AND column alerts are shown.

I'm using 'receive' to avoid multiple calls, one for the source and one for the target.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: So, columns need to be sortable, and fields need to be sortable across columns, right?

Comment: correct, and I need to hook into a single event for each action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use different events to hook into, sortupdate does what you want. Because you are nesting sortables it is also important to prevent event bubbling, this is what causes your double alert. [Here's an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pKVqU/16/)

By the way, when dragging a field to another column the sortupdate handler is called twice because two columns changed.

Comment: Hi Joroen, Thanks for the reply. I have been trying to use stopPropegation() and preventDefault() unsucccesfully. I have not come across stopImmediatePropagation(). I was using the recieve event to get around the double call to the handler. I guess I'll have to look at the ui.item to handle just the recieve, is that the recomendation?

Comment: Did you see my last updated fiddle? It uses the receive event for field drops, and the update event for field order changes (also gets fired when changing columns). This way I think you have all hooks you need to update your model! And yes, you can check what field you're dealing with using the ui parameter